# mirroring Terminal with gets Ruby

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems

There may be a good gem out there for this, but I've run out of Google.

I'm creating a command line interface with a basic `gets` each inputed command. I also want to have basic terminal features like hitting the up arrow and having it cycle the history. Are there gems which mimic this or is there a simple way to implement it?

Comment: There's someone blogging about this and making source code available.  You could try here:  http://jstorimer.com/2012/02/16/a-unix-shell-in-ruby.html

Comment: You should check out Readline in stdlib: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html use this open a loop and gets, it supports history and auto completion (irb uses this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to self-promote, but my friend and I wrote a project that is mostly functional with this goal.  Check it out here:  https://github.com/jamez01/arsh

It's also a packaged gem that you can install.

Comment: If nothing else, you can check out the source code to figure out where to go with your project.

Comment: That's awesome! Self-promote away, you should be proud of your work!

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I did a "smart telnet" using "[Readline](http://bogojoker.com/readline/)". I even enabled autocompletion.

It has all the cool features like up down arrow, autocompletion, ...

Take a look at it